# Issue of rendering in react nivo/radar

Tags: reactjs, radar-chart, nivo-react

I got an issue while trying to render a radar chart using nivo/radar.
Here is the result I got
[image]

The dots are not aligned.
It happen after pushing data to the component (update of chart).

Here is the set of data:

```
data1: 2.7
data2: 2.7
data2: 3.3
indexData: "Global"
```

Anyone with the same issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was the issue. It seems to come from a problem under wood. Basically the animation on the radar is the problem..

Here is the "solution" to fix it, just add the radar:

```
animate={false}
```